# API Gateway S3 proxy - get partial response

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to set up API Gateway as a proxy to an S3 bucket.  I've used the [Amazon guides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html) and have successfully deployed an API where you can specify the bucket and the object key in the resource path - i.e. a call to `HTTPS://<API>/{bucket name}/{object key}` will get a 200 response with the relevant content.

As I have some large files on the S3 bucket, I want to support byte-range fetches.  If I directly call S3, I can do this with the Range header on the GET request.  I've tried the same on my API proxy and it just seems to ignore the parameter.  I always receive a 200 response with the full content.

Is there a way I can configure API Gateway to pass through range requests and return a 206 response?

My initial API definition is shown below.

*Edit: To clarify - I'm aware that pre-signed URLs are the recommended approach for managing larger files.  This is not an option available to me in this case.*

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "GenericS3Reader",
    "version": "2016-10-13T23:04:43Z"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://XXXXXXXXXX.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/{basePath}",
      "variables": {
        "basePath": {
          "default": "/test"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/{folder}": {
      "get": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "folder",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response",
            "headers": {
              "Content-Length": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "Date": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "Content-Type": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            },
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Empty"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "400 response",
            "content": {}
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "500 response",
            "content": {}
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/{folder}/{item}": {
      "get": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "item",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "folder",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response",
            "headers": {
              "content-type": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "Content-Type": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            },
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Empty"
                }
              },
              "audio/wav": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Empty"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "400 response",
            "content": {}
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "500 response",
            "content": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "head": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "item",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "folder",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response",
            "headers": {
              "Content-Length": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "Content-Type": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            },
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Empty"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "400 response",
            "content": {}
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "500 response",
            "content": {}
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "sigv4": []
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/": {
      "get": {
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response",
            "headers": {
              "Content-Length": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "Timestamp": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "Content-Type": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            },
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Empty"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "400 response",
            "content": {}
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "500 response",
            "content": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Empty": {
        "title": "Empty Schema",
        "type": "object"
      }
    },
    "securitySchemes": {
      "sigv4": {
        "type": "apiKey",
        "name": "Authorization",
        "in": "header",
        "x-amazon-apigateway-authtype": "awsSigv4"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html) carefully, you will see that:

> The payload size limit is 10 MB. See API Gateway quotas for
> configuring and running a REST API.

Because the payload is also base64 encoded, this means that in practice, you will hit a limit even for files smaller than 10MB.

API Gateway isn't supposed to be used for serving big files. The recommended way is to use API Gateway with Lambda Integration to create pre-signed urls and redirect your users there.

Comment: Yep - I'm aware of the 10Mb limit - that's actually why I'm looking at the partial range fetches.  I'm unable to use pre-signed URLs due to organisational restrictions - API Gateway has been mandated.  I've looked at building a lambda to do the byte-range fetches, but I'm wondering whether API Gateway could just pass through the header and get a 206 response directly, since S3 supports it.